# Intercept term of logistic regression in ADMM algorithm

Tags: logistic, optimization, sparse, convex

On page 66, the authors of [article](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) of ADMM says that the algorithm can be modified to obtain the intercept term easily in the sparse logistic regression model. Can someone explain this **easy** modification, please?

(We assume that the intercept term is not penalized. So adding a column of ones to the design matrix does not solve the problem.)